# Un-curl operator?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I would like to use Stokes' Theorem to find the area of a surface over a given region. This is given by:

$A = \oint\vec{F}\centerdot d\vec{r}$

but only if the following condition holds:

$(\vec{\triangledown}\times\vec{F})\centerdot \vec{n} = 1$

where $\vec{n}$ is the normal to the surface. How do I come up with a vector field, $\vec{F}$, that satisfies this condition?  I found a paper that discusses an inverse-curl operator [here](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2008arXiv0804.2239S/.), but this is only useful if I know what $(\vec{\triangledown}\times\vec{F})$ is and need to find $\vec{F}$.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is your surface nonplanar? If so, this is going to be difficult. Imagine a sphere with a small hole in it; what does $\nabla\times F$ have to look like?

Comment: @Rahul Narain: Yes, the surface is non-planar.  In fact, the specific surface I'm interested in is $z=\sin(x)\sin(y)$. If I use $\vec{F}=\langle0,x,0\rangle$ it satisfies the condition, but it doesn't encode any information about z, so it would give the same answer regardless of z.

Comment: Essentially this is a vector boundary problem in $\mathbf{G}=\nabla\times\mathbf{F}$ defined by $$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{G}=0,$$ $$\mathbf{G}|_{\partial\Omega}\cdot\mathbf{n}=1.$$ The vector field $\mathbf{F}$ can be recovered from $\mathbf{G}$ via the [Helmholtz theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition#Statement_of_the_theorem).

Comment: @anon You should have posted this as answer, this question still shows up as unanswered

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [anon put it in a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33201/un-curl-operator#comment132141_33201):

> Essentially this is a vector boundary problem in $\mathbf G = \nabla \times \mathbf F$ defined by
>   $$\begin{align}
> \nabla \cdot \mathbf G &=0\\
> \mathbf G \vert_{\partial \Omega}\cdot \mathbf n &= 1
> \end{align}$$
>   The vector field $\mathbf F$ can be recovered from $\bf G$ via the [Helmholtz theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition#Statement_of_the_theorem).