# Surface Integral when a Surface Normal is non-obvious

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals

We have a vector field $\mathbf{F} = 0.4 (-\mathbf{i}-\mathbf{j}+\mathbf{k})$ and want to calculate the flux through a window which consists of joining, in turn, the following points with straight line segments: $(1,1,0),(1,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,1,1),(1,1,1),(1,1,0)$
Which gives a weird looking wedge shape pictured below:
[image]

Since this loop does not have an easily definable normal vector which we can use to find the flux using $\int_S \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{dS} = \int_S \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat n}\,dS$, I was unsure how to proceed. I know we basically want to find the cross section from the vector fields point of view, so to speak, and when viewing the loop along the direction of the force, we see:
[image]

And I could find this cross section from here, but am looking for a method that doesn't involve looking at the physical cross section and summing triangle areas. Is there a way to do this "normally" (without heavily relying on geometry)?

Comment: You can divide it into two, one that is in $z$ plane (horizontal) and the part which is vertical.

Comment: @MathLover you're sure this won't double count some regions from the vector field's perspective? A small elucidation would be very helpful!

Comment: Actually I misread one of the coordinates. So it is not just one horizontal and one vertical part.

Comment: If you are familiar with Stokes Theorem then [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1800396/357854) might have what you're looking for in the second formula $\big($after replacing $B$ with $F\big)\;$

Comment: @greg, I realised it is a trivial problem if you consider three vector fields, each corresponding to the components in the $\mathbf{i ,j, k}$ direction of our original field, perform integrals for each and then add your answers.

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about with adding three vector fields.  Please read the linked [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1800396/357854). It describes how to calculate the _vector area_  (call it $S$) of a surface bounded by a closed-loop path. Then the flux through the surface is $\,\big|F\cdot S\big|.\;$ The nice thing is $S$ doesn't change, so you can calculate the flux produced by any _other_ vector field, e.g. $G$, as the dot product $\,\big|G\cdot S\big|\;$